# Data template not updating cell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to insert a new row (different cell) between two items on a list. The problem is when the new item is inserted, it does not insert the desired cell.

For example, I want to insert item5(ItemCell2) between item 1 and 2:

item1(ItemCell1)

item2(ItemCell1)

item3(ItemCell1)

item4(ItemCell1)

When I insert item5 the cell takes the form of ItemCell1 not of ItemCell2.

Also, I notice that  `OnSelectTemplate` in DemoTemplate is only called once. Thus if the first item of the list is `Visible = true` it applies ItemCell2 to all the rows even thought the list contains items with `Visible = false`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using MvvmHelpers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Demo.ViewModels
{
    public class ItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ItemViewModel()
        {
            var item1 = new Item { ItemName = "Name 1", Visible = false };
            var item2 = new Item { ItemName = "Name 2", Visible = true };
            var item3 = new Item { ItemName = "Name 3", Visible = false };
            var item4 = new Item { ItemName = "Name 4", Visible = false };
            var item5 = new Item { ItemName = "Name 5", Visible = false };

            List = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
            List.Add(item1);
            List.Add(item2);
            List.Add(item3);
            List.Add(item4);
            List.Add(item5);

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Item, Item>(this, "msg", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                DoSomething(arg);
            });

            void DoSomething(Item item)
            {
                var index = List.IndexOf(item);
                List.Insert(index, new Item { ItemName = "Name 6", Visible = true} );
            }
        }             

        ObservableCollection<Item> list;
        public ObservableCollection<Item> List
        {
            get { return list; }
            set { SetProperty(ref list, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Item:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MvvmHelpers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Demo.Models
{
    public class Item : ObservableObject
    {
        string itemName;
        public string ItemName
        {
            get { return itemName; }
            set { SetProperty(ref itemName, value); }
        }

        bool visible;
        public bool Visible
        {
            get { return visible; }
            set { SetProperty(ref visible, value); }
        }

        ICommand testCommand;
        public ICommand TestCommand => testCommand ??
        (
            testCommand = new Command(DoSomething)
        );

        void DoSomething()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "msg", this);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Data Template:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Demo.Templates
{
    public class DemoTemplate : DataTemplateSelector
    {
        readonly DataTemplate dataTemplate1;
        readonly DataTemplate dataTemplate2;

        public DemoTemplate()
        {
            dataTemplate1 = new DataTemplate(typeof(ItemCell1));
            dataTemplate2 = new DataTemplate(typeof(ItemCell2));
        }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            var dataTemplate = dataTemplate1;
            var myItem = item as Item;

            if(myItem.Visible)
            {
                dataTemplate = dataTemplate1;
            }
            else
            {
                dataTemplate = dataTemplate2;
            }

            return dataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="Demo.Pages.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <template:DmoTemplate 
                x:Key="dataTemplate">
            </template:DemoTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
            HasUnevenRows="true"
            SeparatorVisibility="None">
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Found the issue. Changing CachingStrategy to "CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"' fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Changing CachingStrategy to "CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"' fixed the issue.